# CSS3 / Chrome: Anchors not clickable in CSS3 Cube

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ab0Lf117/

I'm not sure why, but in Chrome I'm unable to click my anchors (2 and 4 are working for some reason), even though they're clearly there when inspecting.

I've tried using an `<img>` instead of a background image, I've also tried turning the whole face of the cube into an anchor instead of anchors within divs.

I'm guessing this is due to the transforms but I really haven't got a clue.

It works as expected in Firefox (Fiddle is a bit buggy)

Any help with this would be great as I'm well and truly stuck!

Comment: Works for me. Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit)

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I'm using V 43.0.2357.130 also, however, 32bit.  Do you have any ideas what the issue may be?  The cube "rotates" correctly, the links just don't seem to be clickable for me

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Probably has to do with the z-index, or which display object is currently responding to events.  You might need to raise the z-index of the active span to a high value (e.g. 1000).

Comment: @PaulProgrammer I've tried this too, to no avail :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is originated by the box element being perpendicular to  the view, so it is not "clickable" or "viewable", and then **erroneously** propagating this behaviour to the descendants.

This won't happen with an angle of **almost - but not equal to - 90 deg**

Set this

```
#box {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-89.99deg) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(-89.99deg) rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

and this

```
$("#b1").click(function() { calcRotation(89.99, 0); });
$("#b2").click(function() { calcRotation(0, 0); });
$("#b3").click(function() { calcRotation(0, 89.99); });
$("#b4").click(function() { calcRotation(0, 180); });
$("#b5").click(function() { calcRotation(0, 269.99); });
$("#b6").click(function() { calcRotation(269.99, 180); });
```

and it will work.

I believe this is a new bug in Chrome, I am almost certain that in previous Chrome versions it worked ok (with the preserve-3d style applied)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ab0Lf117/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  Much nicer than the fix I put in place!